# window.move in the negative direction issue

Tags: javascript

I have a section of code that I have been fooling around with. The goal of the code is to have four buttons, when you press the open button a window is opened in the top left corner of the screen, when you press the move button the window is supposed to move in an infinite loop around the screen starting in the positive X direction and moving clockwise. I am having an issue with the window moving in the negative X direction. Whenever the widow reaches the bottom righthand corner of my computer screen it will just stop. I do not know how to fix it, I just figured I would put a negative symbol before the direction that I want it to move. The moving function is under var moveWindow.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var aWindow;
            var current = 0;
            function openWindow() {
                aWindow = window.open("", "", "width=400, height = 200");
                aWindow.document.write("This is my new Window");
            }

            function closeWindow(){
                if(aWindow) {
                    aWindow.close();
                }
            }

            var moveWindow = function windowMove() {
                var rightLimit = screen.width -400;
                var topLimit = screen.height - screen.availHeight;
                var bottomLimit = screen.height - 200;
                    if (aWindow) {
                        if (aWindow.screenY <= topLimit && aWindow.screenX != rightLimit) {
                             aWindow.moveBy(100, 0)
                        }
                        else if (aWindow.screenX <= rightLimit && aWindow.screenY != topLimit) {
                            aWindow.moveBy(0, 100)
                        }
                        else if (aWindow.screenY <= topLimit && aWindow.screenX != rightLimit) {
                            aWindow.move(-100, 0)
                        }
                        else if (aWindow.screenX <= rightLimit && aWindow.screenX != topLimit) {
                            aWindow.move(0, -100)
                        }
                    }   
                }
                function startWindow(){
                        timer = setInterval(moveWindow, 350);
                }
                function stopWindow() {
                    clearInterval(startWindow)
                }
</script>
</head>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="openWindow();">Open</button>
        <button onclick="closeWindow();">Close</button>
        <button onclick="startWindow();">Move</button>
        <button onclick="stopWindow();">Stop</button>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please state clearly what problem you're facing and what the expected behaviour is.

Comment: I cleared it up, is it clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your conditions:

- The inequality (`!=`) will often be true also when you reached the border. This is because the window does not stop *exactly* at the offset you had planned for it.
- The *outer* window size is greater than 400x200 pixels, as there are borders. This makes the values you currently have for `rightLimit` (and other such variables) too tight.
- You are testing for `topLimit` but never for `bottomLimit`. Also there is no provision for something like `leftLimit`.
- You pass the wrong variable to `clearInterval`

Because of several metrics which influence the position of the popup window (like border, minimum distance from the screen's end, ...etc), it will be hard to determine where exactly it bumps into a side. As Windows will not let the popup window go outside of the screen, it will be easier to just let the popup window move and see if it actually *did* move. In case it didn't, then you know the side was reached and the direction should change.

It will also be easier the maintain the current direction in a variable instead of trying to detect what the current direction is based on the coordinates.

For detecting whether the window actually moved, you need a small time delay to allow the move to happen, so I would introduce a `setTimeout` for that. But otherwise the code can be much simplified:

```
var aWindow;
var current = 0; // We will use this to denote the current direction

function openWindow() {
    aWindow = window.open("", "", "width=400, height = 200");
    aWindow.document.write("This is my new Window");
}

function closeWindow(){
    if (aWindow) {
        aWindow.close();
    }
}

var moveWindow = function windowMove() {
    if (aWindow) {
        var x = aWindow.screenX;
        var y = aWindow.screenY;
        aWindow.moveBy([100,0,-100,0][current], [0,100,0,-100][current]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (x === aWindow.screenX && y === aWindow.screenY) { // nothing moved
                current = (current + 1) % 4; // next direction
                windowMove(); // call an extra time to make the move in the next direction
            }
        }, 50);
    }
}

var timer; // better declare it
function startWindow(){
    timer = setInterval(moveWindow, 350);
}
function stopWindow() {
    clearInterval(timer); // <--- timer
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, why would screen.width and screen.height not take in account the bottom and left sides?

Comment: It is not `screen.width` that is the cause of the problem. It is that when you do `window.open`, the `width` parameter specifies the *inner* width of the popup window, so the *outer* width of it will be greater, and so the `screen.width - 400` should be more like `screen.width - 420` depending on window border sizes.